# Pandas Can i duplicate rows and add a column with the values of a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    ID value  repeat  ratio
  0 0  IDx10     6       0.5   
  1 1  IDx11     7       1.5   
  2 2  IDx12     8       2.5
```

and i have a list like this:  `l = [1,2]`

What i want to do is to duplicate every row the number of times of the length of the list and in every new row put each value of the list.

And getting a dataframe like this:

```
    ID value  repeat  ratio  value
  0  0  IDx10  6       0.5    1
  1  0  IDx10  6       0.5    2
  2  1  IDx11  7       1.5    1 
  3  1  IDx11  7       1.5    2  
  4  2  IDx12  8       2.5    1  
  5  2  IDx12  8       2.5    2
```

Comment: you were most likely downvoted for not providing your own attempt, if you can remedy it I'll upvote your question. see [mcve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us do a cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = df.merge(pd.Series(l, name='value2'), how='cross')
```

output:

```
   ID  value  repeat  ratio  value2
0   0  IDx12       6    0.5       1
1   0  IDx12       6    0.5       2
2   0  IDx12       6    0.5       3
3   1  IDx12       7    1.5       1
4   1  IDx12       7    1.5       2
5   1  IDx12       7    1.5       3
6   2  IDx12       8    2.5       1
7   2  IDx12       8    2.5       2
8   2  IDx12       8    2.5       3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) , [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`pandas.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).

```
l = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, len(l), axis=0), 
             columns=df.columns).assign(new_val=np.tile(l,len(l)))
print(df)
```

---

```
  ID  value repeat ratio  new_val
0  0  IDx12      6   0.5        1
1  0  IDx12      6   0.5        2
2  0  IDx12      6   0.5        3
3  1  IDx12      7   1.5        1
4  1  IDx12      7   1.5        2
5  1  IDx12      7   1.5        3
6  2  IDx12      8   2.5        1
7  2  IDx12      8   2.5        2
8  2  IDx12      8   2.5        3
```